# Popup HTML page doesnot show messages unless dev tools are open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I am trying to pass message from my content script to Chrome extension Popup HTML page.
The messages are rendered in the popup page only when I open dev tools. It works perfectly fine.
Here is the script:

Content JS:

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
```

POP UP:

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
     { document.getElementById("text").innerHTML+="<br\>"+request;

     })
```

I have tried another approach to which it works but then messages in the popup page doesnot append.
So i am stuck in both the approach.

Content JS:
The "message" is based on few case conditions where it keeps changing and I want to append all the values and show it in the popup page, it works fine in 1st approach ,but here appending doesnot work.Only the 1st element shows up,other responses simply overwrite it.

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.greeting === "hello")
{
 sendResponse({getmessage: message});}
});
```

POP Up page:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response)
{
const node = document.createElement("li");
const textnode = document.createTextNode(response.farewell);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("MyData").appendChild(node);

});
});
```

I have tried the two approaches mentioned in the description but I am stuck in both approach.
The first approach needs the dev tool to be opened first and the 2nd approach doesnot append the 2nd message to the 1st one while displaying data in the pop up page.

Comment: The popup runs only when shown. It can't receive messages when it's closed. How `message` is constructed in the content script and do you use `all_frames` in manifest.json? You can probably use chrome.tabs.sendMessage from the popup to send a `start` message, then use your first approach.

Comment: I am not using all_frames in manifest."You can probably use chrome.tabs.sendMessage from the popup to send a start message"-Let me try it,will let you know

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested in 2nd  approach. It didnot work.I am appending the code what i have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

Pop up:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response)
{

const node = document.createElement("li");
const textnode = document.createTextNode(response.farewell);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) 

  { 
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML+="<br\>"+request;
 });
```

POPUP HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
    body {
      width: 300px;height: 100px
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
</input>

<div id="text"> </div>
<ul id="myList">
 </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Content JS:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.greeting === "hello")
{
 sendResponse({farewell: "hello"});}
});



window.addEventListener('mouseup', ClickFunction);

function ClickFunction() {
const labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
let l=0;
for (const label of labels) {
  label.addEventListener('click', function onClick()
 {
     txt =  label.innerText;
     b=this.text;
    message='Field: '+txt+';';
    console.log(message);
 
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);

  });
}


}
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
     ],
     "js": ["content.js"]
   }
 ],

 "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
],
  
  "action": {

    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    
  }
}
```